# Modules who have equal support

Tags: commutative-algebra

What can we say about two R-modules, if we know that there supports are equal? What if we know that this modules are Abelian groups? (Z- modules)

Comment: Not much can be said. You will get more useful answers when you add some assumptions and provide some background.

Comment: Say they are Abelian groups, and one is the subgroup of another, and again they have equal supports.

Comment: Not much can be said. It is best when you really outline the whole situation in which this question occurs. And what you actually want in the end.